# Phonegap - Fetch External Website Data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jsonp

I am creating an app using Phonegap (Android) and Javascript / JQuery. I have a Javascript page where I want to read in the text from an external web page. For some reason I am not able to get this to work.

My Javascript page within my app

```
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
        url: 'myexternalserver.com/test.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){

            alert("connected");

        },
        error: function(){

            alert("jsonp error");
        }
        });
});
```

My PHP page on external server

```
// $out is an array of text

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($out) . ');';
```

I modified my Cordova.xml file to include

```
<access origin="http://myexternalserver.com" subdomains="true"/>
```

Am I missing any other steps? I always get a connection error.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have modified my javascript page to the following

```
$.getJSON("http://myexternalserver.com/test.php?var=test&callback=?", {
success:function(data){
            alert("Working");

            var ot = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

            alert(ot);

}, error: function() { 
    alert("Error"); 
}
});
```

I now get the "working" alert but the data reads as null.

Comment: Look at the Network section in the Chrome debugger or Firebug, you should be getting a network response of some sort (200OK or some other status code). What's it say?

Comment: can you verify that the URL is returning content? With Firebug enabled, try doing a `console.log(data);` prior to trying to call `parseJSON` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your server is returning proper headers. I had similar problem with phonegap application until my server returned following headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *

Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

You can read more about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Also check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support attribute *cors*

To enable cross-domain requests in environments that do not support cors yet but do allow cross-domain XHR requests (windows gadget, etc), set $.support.cors = true;

Answer (score 0):

As already said, confirm if you're getting any response whether success or error from the server, I use the developer tools in Chrome for that.

If you're however using the default index.html file generated when you created the app, check for, and allow 'myexternalserver.com' in the  rule for the "Content Security Policy" (CSP) in addition to your current setup.